# Error Trying to Parse a Generic Type whenType is TimeSpan

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing, generics, type-conversion

I have the following code that I am using to try and parse a string to a generic type. In the instance I am using it fails when I try and parse to a TimeSpan. The input string is `"12:34"` which Parses fine using `TimeSpan.Parse` but I couldn't find a solution to implement `<Generic>.Parse`

```
Public Function ParseGeneric(Of T)(ByVal stringValue As String) As T
    Return DirectCast(Convert.ChangeType(stringValue, GetType(T)), T)
End Function
```

Error: **Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.TimeSpan'.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'll excuse some C#, `TypeDescriptor` / `TypeConverter` can help here:

```
static T ParseGeneric<T>(string stringValue)
{
    return (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T))
                 .ConvertFromString(stringValue);
}
```

If I had to *guess* (completely untested) the VB for that:

```
Public Function ParseGeneric(Of T)(ByVal stringValue As String) As T
    Return DirectCast(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(T)) _
                .ConvertFromString(stringValue), T)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, the VB is spot on. Can you explain why a timespan failed because a Date worked ok?

Comment: @MattWilko I it comes down to how IConvertible is implemented in each